# Jackson deserialize an array of object to pojo

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

So i have this JSON file

```
{
      "results":[
          "result":{},
          "result":{}
         ]
}
```

I wish to deserialize it to a java object which contains an array of result objects.

```
public class Foo(){
     @JsonProperty("results")
     private Result[] results;

     public void setResults(Result[] results){
           this.results = results;
     }

     public Result[] getResults(){
         return this.results;
     }
}

public class JsonToObject(){
     ObjectMapper mp = new ObjectMapper();

     public void createObject(String jsonFile){
     Foo bar = mp.readValue(jsonFile, Foo.Class)
     }
}
```

My issue is I keep getting deserialization issues as I have not definied "result".

One way I can get around this is to have `result` as a class variable inside Result but that seems stupid to do and also may cause issues with re-serializing.

How can I convert the JSON so that my class contains an array of result?

Comment: I downvoted for a number of reasons. **First:** That's not even a valid JSON. **Second:** What is `Result` like? **Third:** Your code doesn't compile. You should create a [mcve]

Comment: This isn't the full json as the full one is about 3mb, what is in result doesn't matter as it is contained within a class which would deserialize fine. Yes doesnt compile as it is just an example of what my code would do. I have a class which contains an array of another objec.

Comment: I think @CassioMazzochiMolin's concerns & questions are pertinent to resolving your question. Your provided json sample is an invalid deserialization (it reads as if your `Result` class has a field called `result'. Furthermore, the elements of the array should be valid json objects).

Answer (score 0):

Your question program is wrong. There are many problems with your code. Please use below sample:

```
public class Foo {

    @JsonProperty("results")
    private Result[] results;

    public Foo() {
    }

    public Result[] getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(Result[] results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}

public class Result {
    private String name;

    public Result() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mp = new ObjectMapper();
    String content = "{\"results\":[{\"name\":\"apple\"},{\"name\":\"lemon\"}]}";
    Foo bar = mp.readValue(content, Foo.class);
}
```

Comment: But that doesn't work for what I want. The issue i am having is when i try and deserialize a json file which contains an array of Result objects. E.g String content = "{\"results\":[\"result\":{\"name\":\"apple\"},{\"name\":\"lemon\"}, \"result\":{\"name\":\"apple\"},{\"name\":\"lemon\"}]]}"